# Angular nested directive only the first child is rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `parent` directive which includes two children directives, `first` and `second`. I noticed that only the first child is rendered. Also, if I put some arbitrary HTML markup before the first one, it's all rendered but if I put them after that then they will not show up. Why is this?

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/23260/):

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <my-parent-dir />
</div>

<!-- main.js -->
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("myParentDir", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<my-first-child /> <my-second-child />'
    };
});

app.directive("myFirstChild", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input type="text" placeholder="first">',
    };
});

app.directive("mySecondChild", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input type="text" placeholder="second">',
    };
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use it like this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("myParentDir", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<my-first-child></my-first-child> <my-second-child></my-second-child>'
    };
});
```

From the angular [issues in github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1953):

> self-closing or void elements as the html spec defines them are very
>   special to the browser parser. you can't make your own, so for your
>   custom elements you have to stick to non-void elements ().
>
> this can't be changed in angular.

Answer (score 3):

Self defined tags are no leaf tags so you will have to use:

```
template:'<my-first-child></my-first-child> <my-second-child></my-second-child>'
```

Comment: Thank you. Easier than I thought.

Comment: Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/U3pVM/23262/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using custom tags, you need to close the tag, because *HTML spec* does not allow self closing tags.

```
template: '<my-first-child></my-first-child> <my-second-child></my-second-child>'
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gj50jn0/)